# How to filter by relationship name in neo4j with Condition

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j

I have some legacy code that filters neo4j nodes with Conditions:

```
private Condition addConditionIfExist(String fieldName,
                                      String fieldValue,
                                      String nodeLabel,
                                      Node mainNode,
                                      Condition currentCondition) {
    Node node = node(nodeLabel).withProperties(fieldName, Cypher.literalOf(fieldValue));
    Relationship link = mainNode.relationshipBetween(node);
    return currentCondition.and(link);
```

Now I need to add filtering by relationship name. I tried to add .withProperties("type", Cypher.literalOf("TYPE_NAME")) to link variable, but that does nothing. So, is there any way to add specific reltype to this condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it was a pretty simple solution

```
mainNode.relationshipBetween(node, "REL_TYPE")
```

You can just pass here a String label of type that you want